Is causality necessary for thinking to be possible?
if i think "apple is tasty" i am presupposing causality about eating apple and the effect of tastiness, but this is an empirical thing, we might say there needs to be some interactions in brain for thinking happen but what about idealism? is causality necessary to even think? has any philosopher ever talk about this?
"i exist", in order to think this, does causality have to exist?
is it possible to think this without causality operating?

In order to think also an adherent of idealism needs at least an active brain.
Their brain has to operate according to the rules of physiology, which are causal rules. Hence causality is necessary for thinking due to a trivial reason.
